# 2.8 Python Outliner : Create Collections

Tags: python, outliner, collections

Im trying to make a script to add a set of collections to the outliner as I often setup the same or very similar hierarchy for each my projects. In Blender 2.8 if you right click in the outliner and create a new collection the code is

```
bpy.ops.outliner.collection_new(nested=False)
```

If you try using that in a script you will get an error on the consol

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.outliner.collection_new.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

I have gone back and fourth through the inbuilt API reference to find an alternative but haven't came up with anything that works properly. I expect there must be some fundamental gap in my knowledge about how context works and how to pass correct context.

One thing which seems to sort of work is

```
bpy.ops.collection.create(name="Test123")
```

The problem with that is that the collection is not part of anything, it ends up as orphan data in the blend file and I don't know how to arrange it into the view layer. Once again, I expect there are some simple concepts of implementation I don't know, preventing this from working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work (not verified against any official documentation):

```
myCol = bpy.data.collections.new("Test123")
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myCol)
```